# Docker mechanism to run a script on the host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Does anyone know if it is possible via a docker-compose file (or any other mechanism) to have docker-compose or docker stack (Swarm) start/execute a shell script, which executes on the host docker machine, as part of the normal command?

Healthcheck is the closest thing I could find, but that executes within the container, not on the host.

Obviously, one could wrap the docker command in a shell script, but that option is not viable for me.

Comment: why is not viable please explain that?

Comment: Mainly because the Product Manager told me so.  However, by my comment I was trying to indicate that I knew about that option, thus would not need to ask!  I was/am looking to determine if there any other options....

Comment: One option is to add the containers public key to your host and then from inside the container use the ssh connection to execute commands on host. But that is a highly NOT recommended thing to do. Containers should be used in such way that there least dependency on host

Comment: It seems like there is not really a good way to do updates/upgrades.  Sure you can update individual containers, but if a set of containers defines a product, then that set is not static - it will grow/change over time as releases are done.  I can't 'upgrade' a container that wasn't there before!  Thus, it seems some mechanization to execute a script on the host is required....